# Constructor initializer list vs. expensive operations

Tags: c++, constructor

Consider a hypothetical scenario where two classes can be default-constructed or constructed from each other but either way is considered to be expensive (intentionally contrived example follows):

```
struct PrivateKey;

struct PublicKey {
  PublicKey(); // generate a random public key (1 minute)
  PublicKey(const PrivateKey& b); // find a public key corresponding to a private key (1 year)
  ...members...
};

struct PrivateKey {
  PrivateKey(); // generate a random private key (1 minute)
  PrivateKey(const PublicKey& a); // find a private key corresponding to a public key (1 year)
  ...members...
};
```

(This could of course be condensed to one class but the validity of the question is unaffected. Let's say for the sake of coherence there's no symmetry between one and the other.)

Now there's a structure which holds instances of both and needs this cross-initialization. However, we may need both directions, so initializer lists can't really cut it (they aren't run in the order listed but in the order the members are defined, and no order can be fixed here):

```
struct X {
  PublicKey a;
  PrivateKey b;
  X(int): a(), b(a) { }
  X(float): b(), a(b) { } // UB: a(b) happens before b is initialized
};
```

Of course I could try:

```
struct X {
  PublicKey a;
  PrivateKey b;
  X(int): a(), b(a) { }
  X(float): a(), b() { a = PublicKey(b); }
};
```

but this has multiple issues, of which *running the expensive default-construction* of `PublicKey` in the second constructor of `X` just to throw the result right away is just the first. *There may be side effects* to `PublicKey::PublicKey()`. Both could still be mitigated by creating a cheap private constructor exposed only to a friend `X` which would put the class in some dummy state, but toss in some reference or constant members and *the class may not be move-assignable or swappable*, forbidding any variation on the `X::X(float)`'s body. Is there a better pattern to follow?

Comment: Use `PublicKey *a` and `PrivateKey *b`, and construct them inside the constructor body `{ ... }`.

Comment: @AJNeufeld The answer box is down below.

Comment: Crystal clear. OMG, what was I even thinking? Care to post an answer?

Comment: BTW, losing 1 min over 1 year is not really an issue.

Comment: @Jarod42 Realized that after posting. But I didn't want to have to think of another problem that has similar properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The construction order issue can be avoided by using pointers to the contained classes, instead of embedding the contained classes directly, and constructing the contained objects yourself inside the body of the constructor.

```
struct X {
  std::unique_ptr<PublicKey> a;
  std::unique_ptr<PrivateKey> b;
  X(int) {
    a = std::make_unique<PublicKey>();
    b = std::make_unique<PrivateKey>(*a);
  }
  X(float) {
    b = std::make_unique<PrivateKey>();
    a = std::make_unique<PublicKey>(*b);
  }
};
```

Comment: Maybe, even if the code is self-explanatory, the code should have an explanation, because it could help those in the future.

Comment: You could mention that in practice, `std::unique_ptr` should be used instead of raw pointers.

Comment: Now that you are using `unique_ptr` you should be using `make_unique` in the constructor bodies.

Comment: @NathanOliver Due to multiple suggested improvements, I've changed this to a community wiki.  Additional improvements may be made directly to the answer.

Comment: Made some myself to save others' work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

If the classes are at least move-constructible, you should be able to do this:

```
struct KeyPair
{
  PublicKey a;
  PrivateKey b;
  KeyPair(std::pair<PublicKey, PrivateKey> &&data) :
    a(std::move(data.first)),
    b(std::move(data.second))
  {}
};

std::pair<PublicKey, PrivateKey> computePublicFirst()
{
  PublicKey a;
  PrivateKey b(a);
  return {std::move(a), std::move(b)};
}

std::pair<PublicKey, PrivateKey> computePrivateFirst()
{
  PrivateKey b;
  PublicKey a(b);
  return {std::move(a), std::move(b)};
}

struct X
{
  KeyPair keys;
  X(int) : keys(computePublicFirst()) {}
  X(float) : keys(computePrivateFirst()) {}
};
```

No move assignments happen, only move construction.

Comment: I wish I could accept both solutions. I chose the other answer for its elegance and semantic clarity but yours is perfect if one wants to eliminate the extra pointer resolution at each method call of A or B, as I often consider important.